# Android Runtime Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my andriod app, I get a xml at run time.
How do I inflate the view from the uncompiled xml ?

The xml is choosen by the user from his file system.
Its not compiled.
Hence I do not have any reference like "R.layout.my_layout"

Comment: Please provide the code that's calling the the XML you're getting. You're probably calling it in the wrong way, but we'll need to see what you're doing in order to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [LayoutInflator.inflate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29):

`LayoutInflator.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, true);`

where `this` refers to the containing Activity and `parent` is the ViewGroup you are inflating into.  You can also use this with a `null` parent (and false) if you just want to get back a view hierarchy and add it to a ViewGroup yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This can't currently be done using standard android APIs. The XML files containing the layout needs to be processed during build time to be able to inflate them at run-time

See the documentation of the LayoutInflater here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

> For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML 
>   files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use
>   LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only 
>   works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)

One somewhat tedious option is to write your own XML parser to parse the XML and construct the layout programatically.